# Redefine stdout in FastCGI and Octave

Tags: c++, c, apache, octave, fastcgi

I'm working on implementing an Octave interpreter inside of an FastCGI session using C/C++ in Ubuntu Linux. The problem I'm running into is that FCGI redirects *stdout* to *FCGI_stdout*, but the precompiled Octave headers manage to still use the normal *stdout* which ends up in Apache's error.log instead of printed to the browser.

Do any of you know a way to redirect Octave from using the system's *stdout* to use FCGI's *stdout*? Or even just to have it redirect *stdout* to a file without having to modify Octave's code and recompile.

Thanks

Comment: Compiling in C++, and most of the code is in C++, but all of the print statements seem to have to be done C style (printf instead of cout) in order to work.

Comment: Can you modify the precompiled headers that Octave uses and recompile it?  If so, can't you just do something like `#define stdout FCGI_stdout`?

Comment: I could, but in an effort to make our software more portable we're trying to do this without modifying octave, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question if anybody else comes this way: Specifically setting stdout in octave doesn't seem to work, and neither do any attempts to temporarily redirect stdout at the system level. However, octave has the command dup2, used as described here:

http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/dup2-on-stdout-or-using-disp-on-another-file-stream-td1611884.html

This can be used to redirect octave's stdout to a file to be read by another program (or likely to fast-cgi's own stdout stream once you have the PID)