# Octave Publishing - HTTP

Tags: http, containers, data-science, octave

I am an Octave newbie, I have an octave .m file with a function that takes parameters and execute a simple thing.

Then I want to take this .m file/function and publish it for consumption making an HTTP call. Any pointers?

Comment: these posts may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48261136/4183191 / https://stackoverflow.com/q/53575015/4183191 / https://stackoverflow.com/q/4230200/4183191 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/31560056/4183191 depending on what it is exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: It sounds like what you're asking for is basically the functionality of the [Matlab Production Server](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-production-server.html) product in Octave, which doesn't exist yet. Might be worth hopping on the #octave channel in Freenode IRC or the [help-octave mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/help-octave) to let the Octave developers know this is of interest to some users.

Comment: @AndrewJanke Matlab Production Server effectively allows someone with an existing matlab license to install a matlab runtime engine on a server at a small extra cost, as opposed to having to buy yet another matlab license to install on a server. Octave is free. You can install as many octave instances on a server as you like for free and access it via standard cgi solutions. I don't see how the two are related...

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Matlab Production Server, in addition to running "compiled" Matlab code which does not need a license, provides an HTTP/JSON web service front end for the Matlab code it's running, allowing clients to publish their .m files and consume them through an HTTP call, which sounds like what the poster is asking about. It also manages a live pool of "worker" processes that allow multiple service calls to be running at the same time, and to be executed against "warm", standing-by Matlab Runtime processes instead of paying process startup cost on each call.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou To do the "install Matlab Runtime Engine on a server and run your M-code there", you don't need the Matlab Production Server. All you need is the Matlab Compiler, which allows you to compile your Matlab code to "CTF" DLLs or standalone applications, which can then be run on servers at zero additional cost. If that's all you need – as opposed to an HTTP front-end to a managed worker pool – you do not need Matlab Production Server. And the extra cost of Matlab Production Server is not "small".

Comment: And there's no equivalent of the Matlab Compiler for Octave, because _that_ one really is mostly about the licensing stuff, which is irrelevant to Octave since Octave is free.

Comment: I think probably I don't really understand what the Octave `cgi` package is doing. I'll have a closer look at it.

Comment: Hmm. That Octave `cgi` package does almost nothing; it just parses CGI query strings as far as I can tell. Sounds like this is mostly a case of "build it yourself except for the CGI form query parsing".

Answer (score 0):

The best course of action was to run create a docker container, publish it to Azure Containers and then use a Logic App to trigger the call to the container.

Thank you all.